# What happens when the padding is bigger than the defined size?

Tags: html, css, width, padding

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  width: 10px;
  padding: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>CSS Padding</h2>
<div>This element has a padding of 70px.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried this but don't understand the result. What exactly happens when the padding is bigger than the given width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element will have a width equal to `70px*2 + 1px*2 = 142px`. The sum of the padding and border is bigger than the specified width so it's like you have width equal to 0 and only the padding/border are defining the *final* width

> That is, any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height. The content width and height are calculated by **subtracting** the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified width and height properties. As the content width and height cannot be negative ([CSS2], section 10.2), **this computation is floored at 0** <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing)</sup>

You can clearly see why the *content* width will end being equal to 0 and the *final* width is only the padding and border.

To express this using math, you have the following formula:

```
content-width + padding + border = final-width
```

And

```
content-width = max(0,specified-width - (padding + border))
```

I am using `max()` to express the fact that we take only positive value.

Do the calculation and you will get `142px`

If `specified-width - (padding + border)` is positive, you will get the logical result of `specified-width = final-width`

Comment: That makes sense. But it seems weird to me that the content width is 0 but the content end up having width and existing. It's not overflowing either ( `overflow: hidden` not making any difference)

Comment: @anands it's overflowing on the padding area and overflow:hidden doesn't hide the padding area. inspect the element in the dev tool to notice that you only have padding