# Why isn't the box width fixed to 20px with `box-sizing: border-box`? What calculation is the browser doing?

Tags: css

In the following generated box by element why is the *computed value* of the `width` property not `20px`? Why is it being changed to `32px`?

```css
div {
  height: 16px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>a</div>
```

[image: rendered box]
[image: computed value in chrome tab]

Comment: 16px*2 = 32px which is bigger than 20px so the width is clamped to that value and you end with a *computed* value equal to 32px but the define value is still 20px

Comment: But with `box-sizing: border-box`, shouldn't it prevent the total width of the box from not exceeding the specified in `width` property?

Comment: no, border-box include padding/border in the specified width if possible but it can go bigger and the padding/border are big

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70406454/8620333

Comment: when reading the answer I saw the formula `content-width + padding + border = final-width`. in my example, `content-width = max(0, 20 - 16 * 2) = 0` and `computed-value = final-width = 0 + 16 * 2 + 0 = 32`. is this formula always applied to calculate the final width of any box, regardless of the value of the `box-sizing` property?

Comment: not regardless of box-sizing, that only apply on border-box. For content-box the formula is easier because you simply need to do a sum of all the values, width + padding + border

Comment: wouldn't it be the same formula? with `box-sizing: content-box`, doesn't that make the `width` property already change the width of the content area? so `content-width = width`, in case of `box-sizing: content-box` and so the `final-width` formula would be the same

Comment: yes the final width apply but no the other where you use max

Comment: to conclude, can you tell me where this formula is in the specification?

Comment: You won't find that formula explicitly in the Spec. I made them based on what was described in the Spec. In my answer, I am quoting a part of the Spec that describe the behavior and I turned it into a formula